# icalendar has no attribute "from_string"

Tags: python

I am trying to run a script (I found [here](http://howto.pui.ch/post/37471158372/fetch-publicly-available-google-calendar-data-with)) that reads .ics files (which I got from google calendar). This is the code:

```
from icalendar import Calendar
import urllib
ics = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/calendarlink/basic.ics').read()
ical=Calendar.from_string(ics)
for vevent in ical.subcomponents:
  if vevent.name != "VEVENT":
    continue
  title = str(vevent.get('SUMMARY'))
  description = str(vevent.get('DESCRIPTION'))
  location = str(vevent.get('LOCATION'))
  start = vevent.get('DTSTART').dt      # a datetime
  end = vevent.get('DTEND').dt        # a datetime
```

I installed icalendar over easy_install but when I run the scrpt, I get this error:

```
C:\python test>c:\Python27\python.exe google-calendar-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google-calendar-test.py", line 4, in <module>
    ical = Calendar.from_string(ics)
AttributeError: type object 'Calendar' has no attribute 'from_string'
```

I haven't tested it on linux, but I am sure it will work there... A few months ago I had the same problem with another package. Seems to be a bug? Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, `Calendar.from_string` was [deprecated on 2012-09-15](https://icalendar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id7). A bit further down reveals that you should use `Calendar.from_ical` instead.